# Trying to insert data from one table to another in php MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql, ms-access, odbc

No matter what I do I get a syntax error and I cannot figure out why?

```
$sn= "INSERT INTO [Drive Errors](Serial Number) SELECT [Serial Number] FROM [Drive List] ORDER BY [Position]ASC";
odbc_exec($con,$sn);
```

Thanks, the code works but now all the previous data is being deleted when I insert the the serial number data. Any suggestions?

```
$sn= "INSERT INTO [Drive Errors]([Serial]) SELECT [Serial Number] FROM [Drive List] ORDER BY [Position]ASC";
odbc_exec($con,$sn);

//Selecting table(de) and row(pos) need it in brackets
$sql= "SELECT * FROM [Drive Errors] ORDER BY [Position]ASC"; 

$rs=odbc_exec($con,$sql);
if (!$rs)
{echo("Error");}
```

Comment: Is this the *exact* query you run?

Comment: The database is a ms-access database

Comment: So why is the question tagged 'mysql' and 'odbc'? Are you using an Access Linked Table to manipulate a table in a MySQL database?

Answer (score 1):

You need square brackets around the first `Serial Number`, too:

```php
$sn= "INSERT INTO [Drive Errors]([Serial Number]) SELECT [Serial Number] FROM [Drive List] ORDER BY [Position]ASC";
```

The round brackets are part of the INSERT statement syntax; the square brackets are what delimits column names with spaces or funny characters, or are reserved words in Access SQL.

Comment: Thanks,  the code works but now all the previous data is being deleted when I  insert the the serial number data. Any suggestions? $sn= "INSERT INTO [Drive Errors]([Serial]) SELECT [Serial Number] FROM [Drive List] ORDER BY [Position]ASC";
odbc_exec($con,$sn);
 
//Selecting table(de) and row(pos)
$sql= "SELECT * FROM [Drive Errors] ORDER BY [Position]ASC"; 

$rs=odbc_exec($con,$sql);
if (!$rs)
 {echo("Error");}

$test = odbc_fetch_into($rs ,$result);
if(!$test)
 {echo "Failure";}

Comment: @user3025553 Please click the "edit" button at the bottom of your question and append your updated information there. As you can see, putting code in comments doesn't work very well (because it's not really supposed to be in comments in the first place).